# PHP: Ajax duplicates data in MySQL table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, duplicates, send

Helllo,
I'm trying to send form data to MySQL table using Ajax and PHP. when a form field is empty and sending data, I made sure to display an error message. As many times as this error pops up, I get the impression that this represents the number of entries in my table once all fields are re-signed correctly. Suddenly, when I look in my table, I see that the data from the forms has been duplicated in the table. I cannot understand this. Does my AJAX code keep data in memory, then send it back to php once the data is filled in correctly? Below, I present my AJAX code which allows me to send the form data.

```js
function send(){
    $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#loader").toggle();
    document.getElementById("go").disabled = true;
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    //alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_to.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //async: false,
        data: new FormData(this),                         
        success: function(data,status){
            if(data == 'success'){
                $("#resultat").html('<strong style="color:green;">Thank you Your transaction has been sent</strong>');
                $("input[type=text]").val(""); // Vider le formulaire
                $("input[type=number]").val(""); // Vider le formulaire
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("go").disabled = false;
                //location.reload();
                //window.location.replace("./?home&yes");
            }else{
                $("#resultat").html('<strong style="color:red;">'+data+'</strong>');
                document.getElementById("go").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     });
 }));
}
```

MY PHP CODE:

```js
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (user,phone,email) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $sql->bind_param('sis',$user,$phone,$email);
    if(!$sql->execute()){
        echo ('cant create);
    }else{
    echo 'data created';
  }
```

Comment: _Where_ are you checking whether form fields are left empty? I don’t see anything like that in the code you have shown, so presumably this happens on the server side? Then this has nothing whatsoever to do with “keeping data in memory” - if _you_ deliberately make an AJAX request every time the form is submitted, regardless of whether the data is complete yet or not, then the problem clearly lies with what you are dong with the data in PHP.

Comment: Please add your PHP code, as this is the important part of it

Comment: What exactly triggers your `send()` function? Because every time that function runs, you're adding a new "submit" event handler to your form. But you aren't removing the earlier handlers, so then if send() is run more than once, then every time the form gets submitted it will trigger _all_ the handlers added to the form, and thus will submit the form data multiple times. This is a classic design pattern mistake that a lot of beginners make. You need to ensure you only add the submit handler _once_.

Comment: @ADyson: Can you please show me what to do ?

Comment: @ADyson, as you said, i have found, you are right.
I just added : ("#form").unbind(); after processData: false, in the javascript code.
it work fine without duplicate entries event if i make more submit.

Comment: That's good, although the most ideal solution would be simply to define the submit handler once, outside the 
send() function. Also the equivalent opposite function to on() is off(). If you read the documentation for unbind() you'll see that it's actually the opposite to bind(), and also that it's deprecated. So if you want to do it this way you must use off() instead of unbind() (they don't behave exactly the same way in all situations)